# Doctrine 2 way too slower than Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: doctrine-orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to use **Doctrine 2** ([LaravelDoctrine](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.0/orm)) instead of **Eloquent**.

Performing simple query of getting paginated data:

```
// Doctrine
$orders = $this->orderRepository->paginateAll(50);
// Eloquent
$orders = $this->orders->paginate(50);
```

I end up with **Doctrine queries taking too much time** (info from Laravel Debugbar):

- **Doctrine queries** took `3.86s`

1.79s

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_0 FROM (SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.customer_id AS customer_id_1, o0_.customer_ref AS customer_ref_2, ... FROM orders o0_) dctrn_result LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

16.63ms

```
SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.customer_id AS customer_id_1, o0_.customer_ref AS customer_ref_2, ... FROM orders o0_ WHERE o0_.id IN (?)
```

2.05s

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id_0 FROM (SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.customer_id AS customer_id_1, o0_.customer_ref AS customer_ref_2, ... FROM orders o0_) dctrn_result) dctrn_table
```

- **Eloquent queries** took `50.38ms`

36.73ms

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `orders`
```

13.65ms

```
select * from `orders` limit 50 offset 0
```

I'm not pasting whole doctrine queries here as there's 65 columns in the table, but they all used with 'AS', identically to mentioned columns.

*Is this is intended Doctrine 2 behavior to be so slow or am I missing something?*

I used annotations as Meta Data for mapping and `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` for accessing the data.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards.

Comment: paginateAll is not a Doctrine repository method.  It's part of LaravelDoctrine.  For whatever reason it looks like whoever wrote it did not do a very good job for your particular case.  I can't even follow your posted queries.  I do pagination all the time using Symfony/Doctrine.  Hardly any overhead.  Not sure what to suggest except maybe asking on their github site.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to use default Doctrine 2 paginator [link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html). And the data retrieving works perfect (~7.1ms), even faster than Eloquent analog. But with count() method I still end up with almost 2 seconds of query time.

Comment: Thanks for link.  I didn't even know that Doctrine had a paginator.  I'm guessing it comes from trying to only have one query as input.  I write custom code form my pagination.  I have a SELECT DISTINCT id LIMIT x that gets a list of needed ids taking into account joins and what not.  Then a second query using WHERE IN to load and hydrate the actual entities.  Sorry I can't be of more help.